# Users cannot select an item from my combobox (VBA Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a ComboBox on a subform and for some reason it is not possible to select an item from the list.

What should I look at to try and fix this please?

I have tried all the ideas I could think of, and have established the below:

The combobox's Locked property is False.

The subform's AllowEdits property is Yes.

The subform's AllowAdditions is No, but changing it to Yes does not fix my problem, and causes another error.

The combobox is bound and the subform's recordset type is an updateable snapshot.

It is a database I have inherited, which now has an Access 2010 frontend, and apparently this combobox did used to work before we migrated over from Access 2003.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the locked and allowed properties at run-time, my VBA is very rusty but are you sure there are no other events in Code being fired when you select an item?